# Ext.Widget "ui" config option valid values, modern toolkit

Tags: extjs, extjs7, extjs6-modern

is there any list of the valid values for the Ext.Widget "ui" config option available?
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/modern/Ext.Widget.html#cfg-ui

I know, some of them are 'alt', 'raised', 'solo', but the documentation does not provide any of them.

Searched within the docs/examples without success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These `ui` configuration values are specific to the different widget classes, so you need to look for them elsewhere, not in the generic `Ext.Widget` class.

For example to get the possibilities for buttons:

1. Head to [`Ext-Button`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/modern/Ext.Button.html) in the documentation.
2. Enter "ui" into the `Filter members...` editbox in the top right cornet.
3. Click on `theme variables` above to check the possibilities (action, alt, confirm, decline, flat, plain, raised, round, segmented, square).

Also check `theme mixins` for variations.